# Removing item from local storage is not working

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am using Ionic 4 to build app weather and I added property to save cities in local storage .

I want to remove item weather city from local storage.

I did like that , but it doesn't remove item from list:

```
  deleteItem(city){
    localStorage.removeItem('cities')
  }
```

My full code including `deleteItem`

```
      // get weather data from provider     
      getWeather(city :string){
        this.weather.city(city).then(data=>{

          if (data) {
            this.weatherList.push(JSON.parse(data.data))
            console.log(data.data)
          //  save city with data
          this.saveWeatherEntry(city, data);

          // test the storage, 
          let entry = this.getWeatherEntry(city);
          console.log(city);
          console.log(entry);
          } else {


          }


        });
      }


      // check if exist before in local storage
      saveWeatherEntry(city, data) {
        let items_json = localStorage.getItem('cities');
        let items = [];
        if(items_json) {
           items = JSON.parse(items_json);
           let city_index = -1;
           for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              if(items[i].city == city) {
                city_index = i;
                break;
              }
           }

           if(city_index != -1) {
              items[city_index].data = data;
           } else {
              items.push({
                 city: city,
                 data: data
              });
           }

        } else {
           items.push({
              city: city,
              data: data
           });
        }   
        //save changes
        localStorage.setItem('cities', JSON.stringify(items));
      }

      // check if exist before in local storage
      getWeatherEntry(city) {
        let items_json = localStorage.getItem('cities');
        if(items_json) {
          let items = JSON.parse(items_json);
          let city_index = -1;
          for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             if(items[i].city == city) {
               return items[i].data;
             }
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

    // delete item          
    deleteItem(city){
        localStorage.removeItem('cities')
      }
```

Any solution please?

Comment: You should use [@ionic/storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage#readme) for an ionic app.

Comment: @AugustinR . the local storge l used above it is working fine , but the problem is l don't know how to delete it

Comment: localStorage.removeItem('cities') does clear the whole localStorage item. But by the sound of it, you want to clear 1 city from the list of cities in localStorage? In that case you need to parse the array back from localStorage (cities list), manipulate the list (remove city), and then set the item again.

Comment: Thank you very , much . could you please help to write code again ?

Comment: like what you said , because i am beginner